# How can one go about writing with a full time job?

Tags: creative-writing, planning, first-time-author, time-management, habits

I'm a single working professional who after work, chores, and sleep can manage to find only a few hours to sit down and write each day.

I do however try to religiously read everyday. Writing seems to take more effort from my part.

Can anyone share an outlook they developed to help them keep constant and focused in their writing habits?

Answer (score 7):

A few hours?  Why, that's a good amount of time.  If you sit down and write for them, you will be able to write a lot of works.

Some things that may help are having a set scheduled time in which you must write -- or sit at your writing desk and do nothing -- or having a minimum daily quota, which should be longer than the amount of writing it takes you to warm up.